# How to benchmark DB operations using JMH?

Tags: benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

Sometimes we have to perform same DB operation multiple times within a loop. How can I compute the execution time for each operation using JMH?

```
public void applyAll(ArrayList<parameter_type> lists) {
    for(parameter_type param : lists) {
        saveToDB(param);
    }
}
```

How can I compute the execution time for saveToDB(param) for each time it is being executed/called?

Answer (score 1):

DB operations are really nothing to microbenchmark. Their will depend on multiple things that are quite impossible to isolate.

As for using parameters, [have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29012346/1237575) that explains the use of the `@Param` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

As @RafaelWinterhalter said, this type of calls are prone to give misleading results in benchmarks. But if you still want to try, then:

1. Serialize and save a reference list of calls.
2. Then in a benchmark use a `@State(Scope.Thread)` object to restore this list to an array and have a loop counter variable there.
3. Then `@Benchmark public int test1_saveToDB(MyState state) { saveToDB(state.params[state.i]); return state.i++; }`